# How to print out values of dictionary in a list of another dictionary

Tags: python, jinja2

I'd like to do is render/display **isbn** and **work_ratings_count** values on bookdetail.html

res output is:

```
{'books': [{'id': 29207858, 'isbn': '1632168146', 'isbn13': '9781632168146', 'ratings_count': 0, 'reviews_count': 2, 'text_reviews_count': 0, 'work_ratings_count': 28, 'work_reviews_count': 123, 'work_text_reviews_count': 10, 'average_rating': '4.07'}]}
```

code:

```
import requests, json

res= requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "xxx", "isbns": "9781632168146"})

JS = res.json()
bs = json.loads(JS)
print(bs.get['isbn'])
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hello, are you trying use jinja standalone or are you using it with flask?

Comment: Using it with flask. I eventually got my way around it. Thanks JS[‘books’][0][‘work_ratings_counts’] gave me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might make things easier on yourself if you set up your data differently. Why not use nested dictionaries?

```
nested_dict = {"book": {"ISBN": 0000, "Num": 0001}, "book2": {"ISBN": 0000, "Num": 0001}}
```

Then to print you can call the key/value as:

```
nested_dict["book2"]["ISBN"]
```

Hope this helped, if I misinterpreted your question let me know.

Comment: @Kayode is asking how to render to an HTML. not about restructuring the data set.

Comment: @rohitkeshav i misunderstood the question then, apologies.